# Shorten Long if Statement in php

Tags: php

I am by no means a PHP expert.  I can read it somewhat but writing it is beyond me.  I am trying to find the shortest most efficient way to write this if statement. It is for a filter on my site.  The filter shows a business based on the selection the user makes.  The issue is i dont know how to code it to where the user can select multiple filters.  I am pretty sure it has to do with my && statements.  Please look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong.  I have searched but I could not find anything that is unique to my situation.

```
if($tghtcrl!="" && $lsecrl!="" && $wavy!="" && $strt!="")
    {

$vWhereClause .= " AND (specialty='".$wavy."' OR specialty='".$strt."' OR specialty='".$tghtcrl."' OR specialty='".$lsecrl."')";
    }
    else
    {
        if($tghtcrl!="")
        {
            $vWhereClause .= " AND specialty='".$tghtcrl."' ";
        }
        if($lsecrl!="")
        {
            $vWhereClause .= " AND specialty='".$lsecrl."' ";
        }
        if($wavy!="")
        {
            $vWhereClause .= " AND specialty='".$wavy."' ";
        }
        if($strt!="")
        {
            $vWhereClause .= " AND specialty='".$strt."' ";
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated sirs.  The else statement takes care of the singular selections and the beginning if statement takes care of selecting all 4.  But what about selecting in between.  I feel like the answer is staring me in my face. Code below is the updated code provided by @h2ooooooo.

```
 if($tghtcrl!="" && $lsecrl!="" && $wavy!="" && $strt!="")
{
    $vWhereClause .= " AND (specialty='".$wavy."' OR specialty='".$strt."' OR specialty='".$tghtcrl."' OR specialty='".$lsecrl."')";
}
else
{
    $variables = array($tghtcrl, $lsecrl, $wavy, $strt);
    foreach ($variables as $variable) 
    {
        if ($variable!="")
        {
            $vWhereClause .= " AND specialty='".$variable."' ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're completely open to SQL injection attacks. If you use `mysql_` then you need to stop ASAP.

Comment: And a note about @h2ooooooo's comment, your SQL injection vulnerability is a separate issue to still using `mysql_*`

Comment: @h2ooooooo you say that as if concatenating user input into a query is somehow safe in PDO/MySQLi...

Comment: The MySQL extension is deprecated and doesn't have *very good* mechanisms for safely querying the database. I suggest you switch to MySQLi / PDO and use parameterized queries (for preventing SQL injection).

Comment: You guys obviously see something that I do not in my code.  I am a PHP novice. At current time I am taking a course on Lynda and am not very far.  Can you please explain more if you have the time?  Thanks.

Comment: Our "usual" message: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from your obvious SQL injection (which you can read about with a simple google search), you can just use a loop to check through the values as so:

```
$values = array($tghtcrl, $lsecrl, $wavy, $strt);
$sqlValues = array();

foreach ($values as $value) 
{
    $value = trim($value);
    if ($value != "") 
    {
        $sqlValues[] = "specialty = '" . $value . "'";
    }
}

if (!empty($sqlValues)) 
{
    $vWhereClause .= " AND (" . implode(" OR ", $sqlValues) . ")";
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply.  The variables were exactly what I was looking for but the if statement still only shows businesses if all four filters are selected. I need for it to filter even if only 2 are selected or 3. Also I am completely ignorant of the dangers of SQL Injections. What is the actual issue that I have with my code? Thanks for your time again.

Comment: @EjofUZM I don't know where you get `$wavy` etc from, but if you get if from ANY user input value, then imagine if I input `' OR 1 = 1 --` into the `$wavy` field. Suddenly your code would say ` AND specialty='' OR 1 = 1 --`. The last `--` would ignore the rest of the query, and I could suddenly see all your rows. If you allow multiple queries I could even use `wavy='; DROP TABLE users; --` which would delete your entire users table (or any other table).

Comment: Hey sir i did some research into the sql injections. The $wavy etc information comes from the database.  There are no user inputs for the user to search on my site.  These functions are specifically for filtering information already present in the database.  As far as as protecting my site from sql injections that is at the top of the list now. Also I am using Boonex Dolphin CMS if that makes any difference.
But in regards to the current situation would you be able to give me the best way to go about achieving my goal?

Comment: @EjofUZM What I would do if I was you is output your entire SQL query before you run it and check it through manually (or be lazy and paste it here and I'll look through it). Usually my workflow when encountering SQL bugs like this is the following: 1. Find out that there's a bug 2. Output the SQL 3. Test that SQL directly in the database (PHPMyAdmin is awesome at this) 4. Now I've isolated whether it's a PHP problem or a MySQL problem (and I've probably gotten the error message as well!)

Comment: Im dont think im having a bug issue i think i just coded it wrong.  The $vWhereClause statement is only running if the 4 variables ($tghtcrl!="" && $lsecrl!="" && $wavy!="" && $strt!="") are selected.  Im just trying to rewrite this so that all 4 variables dont have to be selected to display the filtered content. Im pretty sure it is the && operators as well as the first $vWhereClause statement. Im pretty sure adding your new variables to the begininning if statement is the way to go I just dont know how to do it. Im sure the answer is simple. Please let me know if i am being unclear.

Comment: @EjofUZM I think the important question here is that you're doing 2 different things in code. Do you want it to be ALL of them that should match (you used `AND`) or ANY of them (then you'd use `OR`)?

Comment: I think the answer to that would be All, Some and None. Which i guess is ANY. This is why i liked your array because i dont want the matching to be limited to a set 1 of the 4 variables.  Right now its Select All, Select None or Select Just 1 which the else statement takes care of. I cant select 2 or 3 variables.

Comment: @EjofUZM I've updated my answer for you. That should take care of everything (and as a bonus - ignores whitespace). If you ever change your mind and you want them all to match, just change `" OR "` to `" AND "`.

Comment: I wish i could kiss you dude... I have been sitting at this computer for 6 hours on this shooting in the dark... Works perfectly!

Comment: @EjofUZM I'm glad I could help! Have a great evening. :-)

Comment: one more small question.  I came across this issue while testing. I currently have listings that have more than one specialty.  For example a normal specialty would be Specialty: Wavy. But a listing with multiple specialties would look like this Specialty: Wavy, Straight, Curly.  Currently the filter is excluding the listing with multiple values even though it holds a filtered value. So currently if i were to filter wavy i would only see the first listing and not the second one with multiple specialties. What could i do to fix this?

Comment: After another couple of hours i figured it out.

$sqlValues[] = "specialty LIKE '%" . $value . "%'";